# Two foreign keys referencing same primary key cause cycles or multiple cascade paths, but why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am trying to define some constraints on some tables in my database:

`Destinations`: `ID` (PK), `Description`
`Pallets`: `ID` (PK), `ID_Destination1`, `ID_Destination2`

I would like to define `ID_Destination1` and `ID_Destination2` as foreign keys referencing `ID` of `Destinations`.

However, when I try to define these foreign keys with constraints `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and `ON DELETE SET NULL`, I get the following error:

> `Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_PalletDest1' on table 'Pallets' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

I managed to create the table defining only one foreign key with constraint `ON UPDATE SET NULL` `ON DELETE SET NULL`, but I couldn't create both foreign keys.

I read that one solution could be to set `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` and `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and to manage update/delete of `Destinations` within the code.

Why do these relations maybe cause cycles?

How do I bypass this error?

Comment: Sql server can't handle when multiple FKs can trigger action at the same time (ie. Delete). Since you want a delete, it should be enough one FK cascades. You might though look into your design, destination1, destination2 might be a sign you need to have a separate destination table

Comment: Imagine just you have the same value for ID_Destination in  the INSERT of a Pallet... Which rule will be used for both values ???  Pallets: ID (PK), ID_Destination1, ID_Destination2. Your rule is inconsistant...

Comment: Why would having the same value for ID_destination be a problem? When I add the foreign key constraint, I thought that the database would just check that the value inserted exists in the referenced table... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Cascading deletes that would follow "multiple cascade paths" are simply not supported.  It could be done, and there have been requests to implement it for years, but it's never been prioritized.

You can see and vote for feedback items here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0?q=multiple+cascade+paths